# How to Save and Load session file with other name in WtelegrameClient libary, c#?

Tags: c#, telegram, wtelegramclient

I use wtelegramclient library to sign in a telegram account via api 
WTelegramClient saves (typically in the encrypted file bin\WTelegram.session) its state and the authentication keys that were negociated with Telegram so that you needn't sign-in again every time. 
But I want save with other path name and load it 
So How to do it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

add

```
case "session_pathname": return "sessions/filename.session";
```

to your config like this:

```
 string Config(string what)
    {
        switch (what)
        {   
            case "api_id": return Properties.Settings.Default.api_id;
            case "api_hash": return Properties.Settings.Default.api_hash;
            case "phone_number": return Properties.Settings.Default.phone_number;
            case "session_pathname": return "sessions/filename.session";
            case "verification_code":
            case "password":
                BeginInvoke(new Action(() => CodeNeeded(what.Replace('_', ' '))));
                _codeReady.Reset();
                _codeReady.Wait();
                return textBoxCode.Text;
            default: return null;
        };

    }
```

sessions is the folder the filename.session is stored in

this will be in your bin/debug folder

Answer (score 0):

By default, the WTelegram.session file is saved in the **bin** subfolder or at the root of your project.

In order to change its name and location, you just need to reply something to `"session_pathname"` instead of `null` in your Config callback.

[See also this FAQ for more information around this subject](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/blob/master/FAQ.md#multiple-users)